# How should I adjust my parameters to be able to detect certain white blobs on top of a black backgroung

Tags: python, image-processing

I have a very simple task which is detecting some very obvious blobs. I am very new to image processing, I am probably making a very simple mistake. I prepared a blob detection function by using [this example](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/find-circles-and-ellipses-in-an-image-using-opencv-python/) and I am using this function on an artificial image. My original task is to detect blob in a much complex image but I thought I can start small. Originally I have a gray image with small whitish(less gray) dirts over it. Anyways my problem is I cannot detect any blobs. I think I am failing on adjusting the parameters. Although I tried many different combinations, I couldn't get any result. Here is my simpler artificial image:
[image]

Here is my code

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
import cv2

def normalizeImage(image):

    print("Normalizing image..")
    min = np.min(image)
    image = image-min #to have only positive values
    max=np.max(image) 
    div=max/255 #calculate the normalize divisor
    image_8u = np.uint8(np.round(image / div))
    return image_8u

def detectBlobs(dustImage):
    print("Detecting blobs...")

    pp = cv2.SimpleBlobDetector_Params()

    pp.filterByArea = True# Set Area filtering parameters
    #minDiameter = 1
    #maxDiameter = 5 
    pp.minArea = 100 #3.14159 * minDiameter * minDiameter
    #pp.maxArea = 3.14159 * maxDiameter * maxDiameter 

    pp.filterByCircularity = True # Set Circularity filtering parameters
    pp.minCircularity = 0.9

    pp.filterByConvexity = True  # Set Convexity filtering parameters
    pp.minConvexity = 0.2

    pp.filterByInertia = True  # Set inertia filtering parameters
    pp.minInertiaRatio = 0.1

    detector = cv2.SimpleBlobDetector_create(pp)  # Create a detector with the parameters
    keypoints = detector.detect(dustImage) # Detect blobs
    numberOfBlobs = len(keypoints)

    if(numberOfBlobs > 0):
        print(numberOfBlobs + "blobs detected!")
        blank = np.zeros((1, 1))# Draw blobs on our image as red circles
        blobs = cv2.drawKeypoints(dustImage, keypoints, blank, (0, 0, 255), cv2.DRAW_MATCHES_FLAGS_DRAW_RICH_KEYPOINTS)

        text = "Number of Circular Blobs: " + str(len(keypoints))
        cv2.putText(blobs, text, (20, 550), cv2.FONT_HERSHEY_SIMPLEX, 2, (0, 100, 255), 3)
        # Show blobs
        cv2.namedWindow('img', cv2.WINDOW_NORMAL)
        cv2.resizeWindow("img", 900 ,900)
        cv2.imshow("img", blobs)
        cv2.waitKey(0)
        cv2.destroyAllWindows()
    else:
        print('No blobs detected')
    return numberOfBlobs

if __name__ == '__main__':
    img0 = plt.imread('artificial.png')
    #plt.imshow(img0)
    #plt.show()
    img1 = normalizeImage(img0)
    img2 = cv2.cvtColor(img1, cv2.CV_8UC1)
    detectBlobs(img2)
    exit()
```

Comment: [labeling](https://scikit-image.org/docs/stable/auto_examples/segmentation/plot_label.html) may solve this problem

Comment: Try thresholding and then `cv2.findContours`.